# can't import any non-standard library python3

Tags: import

i use python 3 in an IDE and try to import some libraries like pandas using :
''' import pandas as pd '''
bu i get this error:
''' no module named 'pandas' '''
what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pandas first
Use pip install pandas in command prompt
If it give error include pip in system variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a virtual machine. First activate the virtual machine in the terminal and then use the command

```
>>> pip install pandas
```

Comment: i have had this done in my command prompt and the package is installed but in my IDE(i use Pycharm) i get the same error.( no module named pandas)